# Null Object in Backend Controller

Tags: c#, .net, angular8

I'm passing several Objects from Angular 8 frontend to C# backend service.The values are set in the front end,but  when it comes to the backend its null.

This is the Angular 8 UI Front End

```
this.internalreport = { file_hash: this.file.sha1, values: this.values, date: new Date() };
            this.http.post('api/InternalReport/create', [
              this.internalreport,
              this.file]
            , { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => {
                if (data.status == 200) { console.log("success");}
              }, err => { console.error('Observer got an error:');});
}
```

This is the controller method

```
 [HttpPost("create")]
 public ActionResult<InternalReport> Create([FromBody]InternalReport report,[FromBody]File file)
 {
 }
```

Both file and report is null

Update:

Updated the UI code like this

```
let params2 = new HttpParams().append("file", JSON.stringify(this.file));
            
            this.internalreport = { file_hash: this.file.sha1, values: this.values, date: new Date() };
            params2.append("report", JSON.stringify(this.internalreport));



            this.http.post('api/InternalReport/create', params2
            , { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => {
                if (data.status == 200) { console.log("success");}
              }, err => { console.error('Observer got an error:');});
```

Removed the [FromBody] tag from controller,now the objects are not null.But the values in it except the date is null.

```
 [HttpPost("create")]
        public ActionResult<InternalReport> Create(InternalReport report,File file)
        {
```

Comment: Have you tried passing an json object like `JSON.stringify({internalReport: this.internalreport, file: this.file})` instead of an array

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I think i need to set content type and headers...

Comment: you can only pass one model via the body, so @MohsinMehmood solution should work

Comment: @PatrickBeynio okay... thanks

Comment: you need to manually extract the file you can't use from body twice

Comment: @MohsinMehmood How should the controller method be modified? still its null

Comment: You need a C# class with two properties i.e InternalReport and File lets call this class `ReportModel`. Then in controller you specify `public ActionResult<InternalReport> Create([FromBody] ReportModel report)`. Then, ensure that json body has the following structure `"report": {
     "internalReport": ...,
     "file": .. 
}`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

you can only pass one [FromBody] to action. you should either pass one [FromBody] object containing these parameters Or pass them via query string and without [FromBody].